# The shortest distance between 2 vector lines (R^3)

Tags: vectors

I have this question and the answer to it:
[image: Vectors Question]:

The problem is, to me, that answer just feels like a little bit of guess work. How are you meant to know how to factor is to leave just a number?

Can anybody offer any advice on how I could factor something like this easily or give tips on another, more simple, way to solve it?

Comment: Here's a nice formulae!
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1175206/distance-of-two-lines-in-mathbbr3/1221906#1221906

Answer (score 0):

This is not guesswork at all.

Consider the two generic points that are on each line, $A$ and $B$.

You have $A=(2,3+\alpha,5)$ and $B=(3+4k\beta,3+\beta(1-k),-2-3k\beta)$

You compute the distance between $A$ and $B$ and you look for the minimum of the function relative to $\alpha$ and $\beta$...

Comment: I understand that, just not how they found what to factor the extremely long expression to, to reduce it to (a-b+bk)^2 + (5bk+5)^2 + 25?  

In other words, how did they know what to factorise to find the minimum of the function?

Comment: You see when developping the expression some interesting strings, such as $\alpha^2+\beta^2-2\alpha\beta$. If you put this on the side (it is after all $(\alpha-\beta)^2$, you see also $2k\beta$ associate with $\alpha-\beta$. It is interesting to group them together and see the remaining factors, and from then on to go on reducing the expression.

Comment: Yeah, that was the bit that seemed a little like trial and error/guessing work to me. But if that's the best way then I guess it'll have to do.

Comment: @EulerSAM In fact this is easier than that, and it is strange this is not the way it has been done in your example. You have already from the beginning $(\alpha-\beta+k\beta)^2$ in the expression. No need to develop that early on. The other terms are with $\beta$ only, and you can simplify it.