# Distance between two parametric lines in three dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the distance between the lines $$v = \pmatrix{1\\2\\-4} + \pmatrix{-1\\3\\-1}t$$ and $$w = \pmatrix{0\\3\\5} + \pmatrix{1\\4\\3}t$$

Hello, I'm not sure how to calculate the least possible distance between two lines.  I tried removing one dimension, but it didn't work.  I also tried using projections, but I wasn't able to solve it.  Could I get some help?

Thank you.

Comment: Also see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1175206/distance-of-two-lines-in-mathbbr3.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Write $v=v_0 + tv_1$ and $w=w_0 + uw_1$, where $v_0=(1,2,-4)^T$, etc.. When $w-v$ is the shortest, it should be perpendicular to both direction vectors $v_1$ and $w_1$. Hence $w-v=sv_1\times w_1$ for some real number $s$ (I assume that you know how to find the [cross product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) of two vectors). In other words, we have
$$
sv_1\times w_1 + tv_1 - uw_1 = w_0-v_0,
$$
or in matrix form,
$$
\underbrace{\pmatrix{v_1\times w_1&v_1&w_1}}_{3\times3 \textrm{ matrix}}\pmatrix{s\\ t\\ -u} = w_0-v_0.
$$
This is a system of three linear equations in three unknowns $s,t,u$, but you only need the value of $s$. This can be obtained by using [Cramer's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule). The distance between the two lines is given by the magnitude of the vector $sv_1\times w_1$.

Answer (score 0):

Differentiate distance with respect to both $t$ and $u$ and set to zero. There will be one solution, and it will be your answer.

Comment: Hello, I do not know calculus.  Do you have an alternate solution?

Comment: Sure, now that I think about it, this way is better. Take the vector formed by subtracting a point on line A from one on line B and dot it with the unit vector normal to both lines (i.e, project it onto the normal). Can you see why this works?